Find element atomic mass from compound
I bought a 1962 Nuclear Power Engineering by EL-Wakil
There is an exercise that reads:
Four compounds of one element contain 90.3, 16.5, 26.4, 22.87 per cent of that element by mass. The corresponding molecular masses are 62, 171, 106, 368, respectively. Find the atomic mass of the element in atomic mass unit and identify it
there is an example that states
CO have a molecular mass of 28.010
Carbon constitutes 42.877 per cent by mass in it.
The mass of C in the molecule would be
28.010 x 42.877 = 12.010
This checks perfectly in appendix A
The Chemical Atomic Mass AMU of C 12.010
The solution should be (4th column)
    %       molecular mass  molecular mass of elem
a   90.300  62.000  55.986
b   16.500  171.000 28.215
c   26.400  106.000 27.984
d   22.870  368.000 84.162

I see
56 = 28 x 2 and 84 = 28 x 3 which might mean we talk about the same element
but I cannot find such an element among all the isotopes
What am I missing?
Thanks in advance

For plain text formatting by StackExchange markdown, see as inspiration SE meta - formatting // SE meta -  tables  // Less known formatting tips

Chem+Math MathJax formatting:
Basics / Expressions/formulas/equations / Upright vs Italics / Math SE Mathjax tutorial
// MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

Don't you know an element with atomic mass around 28?

Many isotopes such as $\ce{^{14}_{7}N}$ and $\ce{^{28}_{14}Si}$ would match the data you calculated from the given information. Silicon directly matches your data, and nitrogen would also be the possibility shall the compound contain two atoms of nitrogen instead of one atom of silicon.

The unknown atom is either Silicon, because its atomic mass is $28$. It can also be a lighter element like Nitrogen, with an atomic mass being half $28$. The other submultiples of $28$ do not correspond to real elements. Let's examine first the first probable element, Silicon.
I have tried to find a substance containing Silicon with a molar mass as given in the text of the question. Note that they are all supposed to be known with a precision ± $1$.
The first reported compound has a given molar mass equal to $62$ ± $1$. The only compound of Silicon with such  a molar mass, from my Handbook, is $\ce{Si2H6}$. Its molar mass is $62.17$. Furthermore, the proportion of Silicon in $\ce{Si2H6}$ is $\pu{\frac{56.18}{62.17} = 90.37}$%. This is exactly the proportion of Silicon from the text of the question $(90.3$%). So the substance may be $\ce{Si2H6}$.
The second compound has a molar mass equal to $171$ ± $1$. The only Silicon compound having a molar mass not far from $171$ is $\ce{SiCl4}$, whose molar mass is $169.89$. Now, the proportion of Silicon in $\ce{SiCl4}$ is $\pu{\frac{28.08}{169.89}}$ % = $16.48$%, which is precisely the proportion of silicon in the given data : $16.5$%. So the second substance may be $\ce{SiCl4}$.
The third compound has a molar mass equal to $106$ ± $1$. The only silicon compound having a molar mass not far from $106$ is $\ce{SiF4}$, whose molar mass is $104.96$. Here, the proportion of Silicon in $\ce{SiF4}$ is $\pu{\frac{28.08}{104.96}}$ = $26.75$%, which is nearly equal to the proportion of Silicon in the data : $26.4$ %. So the third substance may be $\ce{SiF4}$.
For the fourth substance, I have not been able to find a Silicon compound having such a high molar mass : $368$. So I don't have any suggestion about this $4$th substance. It may contain a lot of Silicon atoms. It may be a silicone or a similar polymer.
To summarize, the formula of the three first compounds are : $\ce{Si2H6, SiCl4, SiF4}$. The fourth substance is still unknown.
As a final result, the unknown element is probably Silicon. Of course it could be Nitrogen. But no molecule containing Nitrogen exist which have a molar mass equal or nearly equal to the given values : $62, 106, 171, 368$.
As conséquence, silicon seems to be the only candidate for this mysterious element.
